# How to do a Group By and get a Percent Change of Revenue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to do a group by and calculate percentage change of revenue?  Here is my data frame

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
  
# initialize list of lists
data = [['1177 AVENUE OF THE AMERICAS',2020,10000], ['1177 AVENUE OF THE AMERICAS',2019,25000], ['1177 AVENUE OF THE AMERICAS',2018,5000], ['500 5th AVENUE',2020,30000], ['500 5th AVENUE',2019,5000],['500 5th AVENUE',2018,4000],['5 45th ST',2018,9000]]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['site_name', 'year', 'revenue'])
  
df.sort_values(['site_name','year'], inplace = True, ascending=[False, False])

# print dataframe.
df
```

I tried this:

```
df['Percent_Change'] = df.revenue.pct_change()
df
```

It gives me this:

```
                     site_name  year  revenue  Percent_Change
3               500 5th AVENUE  2020    30000             NaN
4               500 5th AVENUE  2019     5000       -0.833333
5               500 5th AVENUE  2018     4000       -0.200000
6                    5 45th ST  2018     9000        1.250000
0  1177 AVENUE OF THE AMERICAS  2020    10000        0.111111
1  1177 AVENUE OF THE AMERICAS  2019    25000        1.500000
2  1177 AVENUE OF THE AMERICAS  2018     5000       -0.800000
```

I also tried this:

```
df['Percent_Change'] = df.groupby(['site_name','year'])['revenue'].apply(lambda x: x.div(x.iloc[0]).subtract(1).mul(100))
df
```

It gives me this:

```
                     site_name  year  revenue  Percent_Change
3               500 5th AVENUE  2020    30000             0.0
4               500 5th AVENUE  2019     5000             0.0
5               500 5th AVENUE  2018     4000             0.0
6                    5 45th ST  2018     9000             0.0
0  1177 AVENUE OF THE AMERICAS  2020    10000             0.0
1  1177 AVENUE OF THE AMERICAS  2019    25000             0.0
2  1177 AVENUE OF THE AMERICAS  2018     5000             0.0
```

The tricky part is to get the percent_change to reset when the site_name resets. I would like to end up with something like this.

[image]

Comment: and `df.groupby(['site_name','year'])['revenue'].pct_change()` doesn't work for you?

Comment: It gives me all NAN results. Weird, because 'revenue' is an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove year

```
df.groupby(['site_name'])['revenue'].apply(lambda x: x.div(x.iloc[0]).subtract(1).mul(100))
```

Also , we usually do `transform`

```
s = df.groupby(['site_name'])['revenue'].transform('first')
df['Percent_Change'] = (df['revenue']/s-1)*100
```

Comment: Yeap, yeap. That's it. Both methodologies work fine. I never understood that lambda thing. Can you please provide a short description of how each technique works? Thanks!

Comment: @ASH the key here is to understand the lambda same as for loop , so that for example , if you only do with one subgroup , what you done without groupby which included in the lambda

Answer (score 1):

You are grouping by both 'site_name' and 'year', hence the problem. I tried the code after removing 'year' and it gave the desired result.

```
df['Percent_Change'] = df.groupby(['site_name'])['revenue'].apply(lambda x: x.div(x.iloc[0]).subtract(1).mul(100))
```